# Word for mental exertion

Tags: single-word-requests

One definition of sport is:

> an activity involving **physical exertion** and skill in which an individual or team competes against another or others for entertainment.

Is there a word for:

> an activity involving **mental exertion** and skill in which an individual or team competes against another or others for entertainment.

AKA (e-sport), but not all mental exertion/skill based activities are done on a computer or game platform. Would competition be the best word use (I feel like this word can apply to either physical or mental events though)?

Comment: Hmm, maybe competition is best. You could use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_sport

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find a single word , but I found this idiom to be very close to what you want (from *Farlex Dictionary of Idioms*, via TheFreeDictionary.com):

> [**a battle of wits**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+battle+of+wits)
>
> a situation in which two people or groups try to defeat each other by using their intelligence (often + between )

Example

> *"The two young geniuses entered into a **battle of wits** as they competed for first place in the national trivia championship. As each candidate tried to defend his stance on the hot-button issue, a battle of wits began as they each produced seemingly endless lists of statistics to support their views."*

I feel this idiom best suits OP's needs since this is all encompassing when it comes to contextual usage.

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U! This looks like a good suggestion, and it's great that you've included a definition (+1 from me). In general, it's best to cite your source, and provide a link if possible. I've added these for this definition; feel free to change or adjust the citation/link if you actually found the definition somewhere else or just want it in a different format. It would also be nice if you added a sentence or two about how the quoted definition fits the OP's situation, just so there's a bit more of "you" in your answer. Good luck—I look forward to seeing more of your contributions!

Comment: Thanks ! I have been looking around on this forum a long time. Thought it's time for me to contribute :) Did edit my answer to specify why I chose the idiom.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you decided to chime in.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use [***game***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/game). Relevant definitions, from Merriam-Webster:

> 1 a (1) :  activity engaged in for diversion or amusement :  play
>
> 3 a (1) :  a physical or mental competition conducted according to rules with the participants in direct opposition to each other

Although not all games would fit your requirement of *mental exertion and skill*, I think any activities that do fit your definition could be called games—and most games, even of the very physical type, also require at least some strategy/mental exertion, at least to remember the rules<sup>1</sup>. This term also seems a bit more specific to me than *competition* (which isn't always for entertainment).

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a fair amount of overlap between *game* and *sport*, with the key difference largely hinging on

- How organized the competition is: games require organization and rules, but not all definitions of sport have this requirement; and
- Physical activity: most definitions of sport, including the one you use, require this—although there is a fair amount of dispute about the level of prowess/exertion required—while definitions of *game* don't generally *require* physical exertion, although they do allow for it.

There's a good discussion of the distinction in [this answer to the question "Difference between 'game' and 'sport'"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/144422/177853).